# login fails to mysql through phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Below are the details i modified in config file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      ='pmapass';
```

I've created an account for pma in mysql

below is the permissions script i ran for pma:

grant all privileges on *.* to 'pma'@'localhost' identified by 'pmapass';

But, when i tried login using [http://][localhost]/[phpmyadmin] (strip off the square braces in the url) and passed pma pair as credentials i'm keep on redirected to the index.php with a different guid kind of stuff in the address bar and no indication of messages in the screen other than the userid/password boxes

MySql version is 5.5.24 that runs on a xp machine.

Am i missing anything in the above steps ?  Can any one advise me on the above

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the date on the server and client.

It is possible that a mismatch there will cause the browser to discard your cookies, effectively logging you out immediately.